# Install 32-bit Python into virtualenv

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have got 64-bit ubuntu (AWS) that I am working on and due to restrictions on the webserver and database I cannot deploy a Django project due to the interpreter being 64-bit. When I make mod_wsgi and point to my python in my virtualenv it builds just fine. But when I attempt to load my mod_wsgi in vhosts it give a wrong ELF class 64 error. My thinking, but please correct me if I am wrong, is that my XAMPP 1.7.3 stack (cannot change this version) is running 32-bit and my python is 64-bit.

I have no problem running my Django project as 32-bit, but how do I install 32-bit into a virtualenv?? Many Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you want it to be 32-bit at all though.

Comment: I am working with an old api that was built with a XAMPP stack that is 32-bit, also I think mod_wsgi 3.4 is 32-bit. Whenever I load the Apache module it will throw an error of wrong ELF class

Comment: Try installing your 32 bits Python inside a VirtualBox 32 bits OS...

Comment: Virtual box is not a solution I'm afraid, I am on Ubuntu server, also will have to use the API currently on the system

Comment: But if your OS is 64 bit, you should install the 64 bit version of Apache and mod_wsgi. Django doesn't care what architecture that end of the stack is compiled for.

Comment: The existing API is built using an old XAMPP stack (32-bit), I cannot change that I'm afraid. I'm an just tagging on a web app to go with it. If I can get my virtual env to use a 32-bit python then I can circumvent having multiple web servers/large virtualization ie the XAMPP stack is serving everything

Comment: You would need to install Python compiled for 32 bit. If you have a 32 bit compiler on the system, try setting the CC environment variable when running configure for Python to the full path to the 32 bit compiler binary. Once you have 32 bit Python installed, work from there.

Comment: Thanks Graham, this got me massively close to having it working. I ended up in other 32/64 bit conundrums though, so it gave me enough evidence to ditch the old api.